# Encontrar los elementos repetidos de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de objectos en el cual se encuentran dos trabajadores, el trabajador_1 y el trabajador_2, tengo que crear un método en el cual resalte las parejas que se repitan en el mismo día, por ejemplo, agregándole una clase.

Por ejemplo, si el trabajador A y el B se repiten el mismo dia en diferentes turnos. Pero si el trabajador A se repite con un trabajador C no se resalta. Solamente resalta las parejas que se repitan el mismo dia.

```
[
{"id": 1,
"trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
"trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
"fechaturno": "2020-12-10",
"turno": "MAÑANA",
},
{"id": 2,
"trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
"trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
"fechaturno": "2020-12-10",
"turno": "TARDE",
},
{"id": 3,
"trabajador_1": "JUAN RAMIREZ",
"trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
"fechaturno": "2020-12-11",
"turno": "MAÑANA"}
,
{"id": 4,
"trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
"trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
"fechaturno": "2020-12-12",
"turno": "TARDE"}]
```

Comment: Veo que ya tienes bastante reputación en el sitio, así que deberías de saber que aquí no hacemos los ejercicios de clase de nadie... Debes aportar el código de lo que has intentado e indicar qué error tienes si quieres evitar que tu pregunta acabe cerrada!

Comment: Quizás te sirva recorrer con dos ciclos anidados el arreglo e ir preguntando con un `if`, si la fecha y los trabajadores coinciden (teniendo en cuenta que no sea el mismo elemento).

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar el método reduce

```js
const trabajador = [
  {"id": 1,
  "trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
  "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
  "fechaturno": "2020-12-10",
  "turno": "MAÑANA",
  },
  {"id": 2,
  "trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
  "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
  "fechaturno": "2020-12-10",
  "turno": "TARDE",
  },
  {"id": 3,
  "trabajador_1": "JUAN RAMIREZ",
  "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
  "fechaturno": "2020-12-11",
  "turno": "MAÑANA"}
  ,
  {"id": 4,
  "trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
  "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
  "fechaturno": "2020-12-12",
  "turno": "TARDE"}]

  const busqueda = trabajador.reduce((t, arr) => {
    t[arr.fechaturno] = ++t[arr.fechaturno] || 0;
    return t;
  }, {});

  const duplicados = trabajador.filter( (d) => {
    return busqueda[d.fechaturno];
  });

console.log(duplicados);
```

también puedes utilizar lodash como lo explican aca https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208001/get-duplicate-object-in-array-using-lodash

Answer (score 0):

Utilize el metodo some para validar si se cumplian las condiciones establecidas y eso creaba una nueva propiedad llamada repetidad que me devolvia un true o false si se encontraba repetido

```
 let trabajador = [
      {"id": 1,
      "trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
      "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
      "fechaturno": "2020-12-10",
      "turno": "MAÑANA",
      },
      {"id": 2,
      "trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
      "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
      "fechaturno": "2020-12-10",
      "turno": "TARDE",
      },
      {"id": 3,
      "trabajador_1": "JUAN RAMIREZ",
      "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
      "fechaturno": "2020-12-11",
      "turno": "MAÑANA"}
      ,
      {"id": 4,
      "trabajador_1": "MARIO GONZALES",
      "trabajador_2": "DARIO HERNANDEZ",
      "fechaturno": "2020-12-12",
      "turno": "TARDE"}]
    
       trabajador = trabajador.map((element, i) => {
      return {
          ...element,
          repetido: trabajador.some((repeated, j) => {
              return i !== j &&
                  element.trabajador_1  === repeated.trabajador_1  &&
                  element.trabajador_2 === repeated.trabajador_2 && element.turno === repeated.turno
          })
      }
    })
    
    console.log(trabajador);
```